# Piping pdffonts to grep

Tags: pdf, grep

So I want to use grep to list the filenames of pdfs that match the search string "Type 1C".

`grep` is supposed to get the data from `pdffonts`, but when I execute this syntax it just executes `pdffonts` normally.

```
find . -type f -iname "*.pdf" -print0 -exec pdffonts {} \; |xargs -0 grep -c -l "Type 1C"
```

When I add `-` after `{}` I get the help file of `pdffonts`, which must mean it doesn't support this argument.

But how can I pipe `pdffonts` to `grep` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's are '-----------------------' included in the output stream and it gets
interpreted as a command switch which messes everything up. So, remove those
pesky dashes using tr before continuing the pipeline.

```
find . -type f -iname "*.pdf"  -print0 -exec pdffonts {} \; | tr -d '-' | xargs -0 | grep 'Type 1'
HelveticaNeueLight                  Type 1            yes no  no      18  0
HelveticaNeueRoman                  Type 1            yes no  no      22  0
HelveticaNeueMedium                 Type 1            yes no  no      26  0
HelveticaNeueLight                  Type 1            yes no  no      18  0
HelveticaNeueRoman                  Type 1            yes no  no      22  0
HelveticaNeueMedium                 Type 1            yes no  no      26  0
HelveticaNeueLight                  Type 1            yes no  no      18  0
HelveticaNeueRoman                  Type 1            yes no  no      22  0
HelveticaNeueMedium                 Type 1            yes no  no      26  0
HelveticaNeueLight                  Type 1            yes no  no      18  0
HelveticaNeueRoman                  Type 1            yes no  no      22  0
HelveticaNeueMedium                 Type 1            yes no  no      26  0
```

You can't use 'grep -l' because there is no concept of files anymore, all that's coming out of there is a stream of text. If you want to maintain the file list as a index then you will likely end up  with a for loop.

Comment: Thank you. I get it now :) I inferred (wrongly) that if grep demands a filename, the Linux command line would be able to take from pdffonts only the filename...instead of outputting the raw data..I assumed wrong. I am new to this. thanks again :)